# Django-models. Complex request to database

Tags: python, django-models, filter

I need to make special request to database through django.

For example:

```
class Model(models.Model):
     name=models.CharField()
     date=models.DateTimeField()
     other=models.TextField()
```

How do I ask for row which name containe word `'Hello'` (it shoul ignor register of first letter)
end it is must be in diapason of date, for example between `2005.08.09` and `2005.08.11`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 8, 9)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 8, 11)
Model.objects.filter(name__icontains="hello").filter(date__range(start_date,end_date))
```

You can stack as many filters as you like and it will be built into a single SQL Query (or whatever database system you use)

Comment: Can i pass this request in method get() if i know that there will be only one result?

Comment: Yes, with Q objects, but the performance will not be any better.